# .net reflection and the "params" keyword

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

In .net, is there a way using reflection to determine if a parameter on a method is marked with the "params" keyword?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does reflection expose if the last argument for a method was marked with 'params'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252656/does-reflection-expose-if-the-last-argument-for-a-method-was-marked-with-params)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Test to see whether the final [ParameterInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.aspx) has [ParamArrayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.paramarrayattribute.aspx) applied to it.

Answer (score 22):

Check to see if `ParamArrayAttribute` has been applied to the `ParameterInfo` object:

```
//use string.Format(str, args) as a test
var method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Format", new[] {typeof(string), typeof(object[])});
var param = method.GetParameters()[1];
Console.WriteLine(Attribute.IsDefined(param, typeof(ParamArrayAttribute)));
```