# Determining if a parameter uses "params" using reflection in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, parameters

Consider this method signature:

```
public static void WriteLine(string input, params object[] myObjects)
{
    // Do stuff.
}
```

How can I determine that the WriteLine method's "myObjects" pararameter uses the params keyword and can take variable arguments?

Comment: How does this differ from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252656/does-reflection-expose-if-the-last-argument-for-a-method-was-marked-with-params ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does reflection expose if the last argument for a method was marked with 'params'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252656/does-reflection-expose-if-the-last-argument-for-a-method-was-marked-with-params)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Check for the existence of `[ParamArrayAttribute]` on it.

The parameter with `params` will always be the last parameter.

Answer (score 22):

Check the [ParameterInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.aspx), if [ParamArrayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.paramarrayattribute.aspx) has been applied to it:

```
static bool IsParams(ParameterInfo param)
{
    return param.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (ParamArrayAttribute), false).Length > 0;
}
```

Comment: If you only want to check for a custom attribute's presence, but don't need the actual attribute instance, then `IsDefined` is more efficient than `GetCustomAttributes`.

Answer (score 15):

A slightly shorter and more readable way:

```
static bool IsParams(ParameterInfo param)
{
    return param.IsDefined(typeof(ParamArrayAttribute), false);
}
```