# C# - Investigating "Method' information using Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

My intention is to investigate the "Methods" of a Type using reflection in order to verify the following :

1. The Methods should be instance methods and public.
2. Takes the parameter "params" and void in nature.
3. The Method does not makes recursive call.

I started as :

```
static void ProcessMethodInfo(Type t)
    {
        MethodInfo[] info = t.GetMethods();

        foreach (MethodInfo mi in info)
        {

          // How to check the conditions here ?  

        }
    }
```

But I don't know how to proceed further. Help is needed.

Comment: I think that item 3 will be extremely difficult to correctly test for. For your purposes, is a method recursive if it is mutually recursive with another method (i.e., method a invokes b which invokes a)?

Comment: Thanks.I am testing for method recursive itself not the mutual one.for example fibonacci series.

Comment: @csharpbaby: Even that will be very difficult and not doable with reflection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if by 3 you mean the *method under inspection* should be non-recursive; then that is a pain - you'd need to parse the IL. But for the others;

```
    Type type = ...
    var qry = from method in type.GetMethods(
                  BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
              where method.ReturnType == typeof(void)
              let parameters = method.GetParameters()
              where parameters.Length == 1
              && parameters[0].ParameterType.IsArray
              && Attribute.IsDefined(parameters[0], typeof(ParamArrayAttribute))
              select method;
    foreach (var method in qry)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(method.Name);
    }
```

Comment: I think using == to compare instances of classes should be avoided. Equals might be overridden, but == usually isn't overloaded.

Comment: You mean for `Type`? That is perfectly valid. I know what you are saying, but the code is fine.

Comment: I wasn't saying the code is incorrect. I was saying using == to compare instances of classes should generally be avoided, because most of the time it's not correct. It's a minor point anyway, but I thought I might just as well leave a comment.

Comment: You were right to do so; I've made the exact same comment in the past ;-p

Answer (score 1):

1. mi.IsStatic, etc - read help
2. [Determining if a parameter uses "params" using reflection in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627656/determining-if-a-parameter-uses-params-using-reflection-in-c)
3. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/sdilreader.aspx

ALL: use google ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to detect item 3 using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following members of the MethodInfo class:

- IsPublic
- IsStatic
- ReturnType
- GetParameters() method

In order to be able to check whether the method is recursive, I think you'll need something more then just simple reflection.