# How to test if a valid Method exists when params are involved

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have the following method:

```
    public MethodInfo FancyGetMethodInfo
         (object obj, string methodName, Type[] methodSignature)
    {
        return obj.GetType().GetMethod(methodName, methodSignature);
    }
```

and for the sake of an example I have in my object I am passing the two methods

```
    public int Subtract(int a, int b) { return a - b; }

    public int Add(params int[] a) { return a.Sum(); }
```

And when I execute the following lines I get these results:

```
        var SubMethod = FancyGetMethodInfo(obj, "Subtract", 
                         new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(int) });
        //I get a MethodInfo
        var AddMethod = FancyGetMethodInfo(obj, "Add", 
                         new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(int) }); 
        //I get a Null reference
```

I'm sure this is because of the params in Add. Is there a clean way to get reference to my MethodInfo for my Add method given an arbitrary sized Type[] containing ints and only having access to the provided variables in my FancyGetMethodInfo method?

Edit:
More eloquently put by Jon Skeet, I want to perform the same binding as the C# compiler does in my method. it needs to work properly with subclasses, implicit casting, arbitrary length params, etc...

Also as requested, a relevant link here is: [Determining if a parameter uses "params" using reflection in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627656/determining-if-a-parameter-uses-params-using-reflection-in-c) which will get me as far as knowing that the method has a params.

Comment: Dont't have VS on my hands, but did you try typeof(int[]) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could:

- Find all the methods with the right name
- For each method:

  - Check whether the last parameter in the method is a "params" array (as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627656/determining-if-a-parameter-uses-params-using-reflection-in-c); thanks yas4891)
  - Check whether the parameter types you've been given *up to but not including* the last parameter match the ones on the method
  - Check whether the *remaining* parameter types all match the array element type of the final parameter

Note that once you'd found a match (and *not* found a match that didn't require this params expansion) you'd then need to *remember* that so that you could deal with the arguments appropriately later (assuming you want to actually call the method).

It's a bit of a faff, to be honest... the way I see it you have three options:

- Change the caller to pass in `typeof(int[])` and your existing code will work
- Change `FancyGetMethodInfo` to handle parameter arrays as described above
- Change `Sum` to accept two integers (or possibly have various overloads)

It's up to you which route you choose...

Comment: how to find "params" keyword has been handled here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627656/determining-if-a-parameter-uses-params-using-reflection-in-c
If you like to include it in your answer

Answer (score 0):

Did you give this one a try:

From the MSDN: [Type.GetMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5fed8f59.aspx)

```
public void MethodA(int[] i) { }

// Get MethodA(int[] i)
mInfo = typeof(Program).GetMethod("MethodA",
    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance,
    null,
    new Type[] { typeof(int[]) },
    null);
Console.WriteLine("Found method: {0}", mInfo);
```

How to check for the "params" keyword: this has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627656/determining-if-a-parameter-uses-params-using-reflection-in-c)

Comment: The problem is that the OP wants to be able to pass in `new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(int) }` and perform the same binding as the C# compiler does.

Comment: ah. You mean so it would still work if you passed `new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(short) }`? Then I got the question all wrong

Comment: @Jon: He doesn't mention that anywhere. It really seems that he just wants to know how to bind to the `Add` method in the first place. He even mentions that he's looking for the case of only `int` parameters.

Comment: @Ken: read the question carefully and see the code samples constructing FancyMethodInfo objects.

Comment: (Less terse responses coming when I'm back on a real keyboard.)

Comment: @Jon: You're not sitting on the subway and browsing SO on your smartphone - are you?

Comment: @yas4891: Close - walking through Hyde Park and doing the same.

Comment: Jon is right here, I really am trying to perform the same binding as the compiler. I will edit my question to make that more clear shortly.

Answer (score 0):

It's not because of the params (although that may pose an additional issue).

Try instead:
var AddMethod = FancyGetMethodInfo(obj, "Add", 
                         new Type[] { typeof(int[]) });

Answer (score 0):

A *params* parameter is nothing more than syntactic sugar for a plain array.

```
    int Add(params int[] a)
```

is equivalent form a CLR perspective to

```
    int Add(int[] a)
```

the *params* modifier is simply C# syntactic sugar.

This means if you want to find you method using reflection you will need the following call:

```
var AddMethod = FancyGetMethodInfo(obj, "Add", 
                         new Type[] { typeof(int[]) });
```

if you further wan to test whether the method contains a params parameter you need to test if it has the [ParamArrayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.paramarrayattribute.aspx) applied to the last parameter of the method.